# browser specific less rules

Tags: css, less

I'm new to less and I'm trying to not show an outline in firefox.  Here's my code current code but I'm not sure how to implement the css hack below.  What's the correct way to do this?

```
.nav_container{
    display:block;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-bottom:solid 2px #eee7d9;
    outline: 2px solid #344656;

@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    .selector {
        color:lime;
    }
}

text-align: center;
&:after{
    display:block;
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e84849;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing LESS doesn't support specific non-standard at-rules.

Comment: What is the purpose of nesting of `@-moz-document` rule inside `.nav_container`? What CSS result do you expect? (Less will put out such `@document` rule into global scope since it is the only correct place for it, but that way it will be no way related to the `.nav_container`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling the `@-moz-document` rule Less don't keep the nesting of the selectors, see also: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2104. To solve your issue you should define the selector relation inside  the `@-moz-document` rule again. Try the following Less code:

```
.nav_container{
    display:block;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-bottom:solid 2px #eee7d9;
    outline: 2px solid #344656;

text-align: center;
&:after{
    display:block;
    content:"";
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e84849;
}

}

@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
     .nav_container .selector {
        color:lime;
    }
}
```